# DMS (Document Management System) / File Repository / File Manager under Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, document-management, dms

I need to create a very simple DMS (Document Management System) / File Repository / file manager or whatever we might call it under Java EE.

It should permit the user to create folders and upload files into it and the folder/files information should be stored inside the database for checking which user created what (in this sense a simple file-manager which only lets one browse directories on the server's disk is not enough).

To be more explicit here's what it should be more or less:

[image: TinyDMS]

So far I searched for canned solutions which I could use however I only found TinyDMS (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinydms/) which is very good (picture above is a screenshot of it in action), it uses jackrabbit for file search however needs a lot of Spring framework dependencies and is a hell to be compiled (didn't succeed yet).
Then there's OpenKM and LogicalDoc but those are really complex programs which don't fit well to be included into a third party application.
Isn't there anything I can start with?

Comment: I would have a look at Alfresco. Even Liferay has support for it. But you are asking for a tool, and that's off-topic for SO.

Comment: I need to use this application inside another already developed application, so I need something between a library and a sample application which can be easily integrated. I cannot use a whole framework like Liferay or Alfresco, so I'm not looking simply for a tool.

Comment: So you have only found big beasts so far. Have you tried Apache JackRabbit? What about using a JCR client and Apache Jackrabbit, Alfresco etc. as a backend: instead of embedding, you could try to integrate it. On top of the `javax.jcr.*` API, use JSF to build a UI.

Comment: Jackrabbit so far is the only thing which I found helpful, yet I find it incredible there's no example on the web of a web program which uses jackrabbit to upload/download/search/show a file tree of all files from which to start developing.

Comment: Because everybody uses a DMS along with with another web application (Alfresco), or the own webapp is integrated as a portlet into a portal server (Liferay). Integration could be as simple as using an `iframe`. Not nice, yes. But look at the time you have invested in compiling TinyDMS, and searching. There is acommand-line client demo for JackRabbit, so go for it, some JSF on top of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [implementing simple Document management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184184/implementing-simple-document-management)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jackrabbit DMS java base.

http://jackrabbit.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t want to use Alfresco, Nuxeo, or other DMS, maybe you should develop your own "Light (DMS)". For that you can start with the repository; for this you could try [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) or [Modeshape](http://www.jboss.org/modeshape) as the lower level to manage data, files, versionong, deletion, etc. Personally, I´m using Modeshape for my graduate project beacuse of it´s documentation and ease of implementation. Then I use JAAS to manage users and its permissions for each file or folder.